# React native: How to navigate nested navigator (wrapped by a component)

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I read on the docs about navigating nested navigator https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html#setparams

```
const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
  routeName: 'Profile',
  params: {},
  action: NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'SubProfileRoute'})
})
this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction)
```

However, my nested navigator `SubProfileRoute` is wrapped by a component

`module.exports = class _ extends React.Component { ... }`

not

`module.exports = StackNavigator({})`

So how do i do it?

Comment: Hey there, gents, I don't see any of the links here working, and I'm facing the same issue you had. I am not sure how to make a regular component have a router (which seems like a necessary thing if you want it to be a part of a navigation tree). Do you know if its still possible to go around this in newest react-navigation and how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to assign the router of the child navigator to the component wrapping it - that way the outer navigator will pass the navigation property to the child navigator.

See [explicitly rendering more than one navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/common-mistakes.html).

Comment: Hey, I don't think you will get notified for the above comment, so let's try pinging you here as well. I am trying to not raise this same question again.

Answer (score 1):

So, I managed to solve this problem on my side. The issue is the links shared here don't work, even though Kraylog's answer provides a good place to start the research.

I found that, in order for nested routers to work, the navigation does indeed look for a child router in the component that it renders. However, it's not enough to set the router property to a child router's for everything to work with, in my example, redux navigation.

You also need to pass the navigation prop manually to the child navigator.

The documentation that helped a bit is this [custom navigator guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-navigators.html).

The solution ended up being a simple one:

```
class MyNavigator extends React.Component {
  static router = NestedNavigator.router;
  render() {
    return <NestedNavigator navigation={this.props.navigation} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is correct, and was in the react-navigation documentation (added by yours truly). It seems that in the overhaul of the website this section was discarded, which is quite counterproductive. I'd suggest re-submitting a PR for the documentation.